# Use Google Earth for land cover classification accuracy evaluation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth, image, land-cover

I am doing land cover classification with an hyperspectral image of Santa Barbara, CA. The spatial resolution is 6.4 meters but I couldn't find any high spatial resolution land truth data for validation. Someone recommends me that I can generate random points in the classification map and see if those points are correctly classified by using Google Earth. However, I don't know how to do that.

Should I download image from Google Earth and put it into ArcGIS? Or should I put the randomly generated points and their classified types into Google Earth?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be doing accuracy assessment. You want to bring the data for validation (Google Earth) into ArcMap. Then you can "truth" the classification for each of your random points in a shapefile. Afterwards you can sample those same points in your classified image and compute your error matrix.

Comment: but could you say that is it scientifically correct to do accuracy assessment using google earth?

Comment: Is using someone else's data that you have no metadata for and no rights to ever scientifically correct?

Answer (score 0):

Imagery from Google Earth cannot be downloaded into ArcMap. There are two options here--exporting your vector data to a KML file and validating in Google Earth or use the ArcGIS basemap imagery and check points within ArcMap.

Comment: but could you say that is it scientifically correct to do accuracy assessment using google earth?